# Only one Occurrence in Java

Tags: java

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    x = new Scanner(new File("C:\\me.txt"));
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<>();

    while((x.hasNext()))
    {
        String a = x.next();
                int num = 0;
                for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
                {
                    if((b.get(i).equals(a)))
                    {num++;}
                }
        if(num==1)
        {b.add(a);}
        count++;
    }
```

I want to add the element to b only when the occurence is only one. But there seems some error i keep getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Or does b.get(i) equal to NULL in first iteration?

```
    if((b.get(i).equals(a)))
```

Comment: What is the error? What is the output?

Comment: The useless and harmful semicolon after `if((b.get(i).equals(a)))`?

Comment: Why don't you debug your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got this error because `b` is empty it doesn't contain any element ,and you are trying to access element in it `b.get(i)` so you got `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, use `contains` to find if the list have that element and if not add it to the list or use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) it doesn't allow duplicates

```
 int count = 0;
 ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
 while((x.hasNext()))
    {
        String a = x.next();
        if(!b.contains(a)){
           b.add(a);
        }
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please

- check the line

  ```
  if ((b.get(i).equals(a)));
  ```

  It contains a semi-colon at the end and I think this is wrong: The next statement in curly braces (`num++;`) is executed every time and not only if the condition matches.
- check if `b.get(i)` is `null` before calling `equals` on it. You know already that `a` is not `null`, hence it would make more sense to check for `a.equals(b.get(i))`
- check the usage of `count`. Its value is not related to the size of the array list, but you use it this way in the loop.In your implementation a situation can arise in which the value of `count` is greater than the size of the list. This results in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I tried to remove it but still an error.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: @Darrius Add that to the question. It is vital information!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're trying to use `count` as the length of `b`. However, `count` is incremented more often than `b` is added to.

Possible solutions are:

- Either update `count` only when you add something to `b`
- or scratch `count` altogether and use `b.size()` in the for loop.